# многократный ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Открывается страница, на загрузке срабатывает ajax, который загружает контент страницы. При многократном обновлении страница падает. Что делать, чтобы избежать многократного ajax при обновлении страницы ?

Answer (score 1):

В обработчике успешного завершения ajax-запроса создавать cookie о том, что вызов уже был сделан, а перед выполнением запроса проверять наличие этой cookie.